# How to load a pre-trained tensorflow model and then inference by torch?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch, torch

Is there any trick to parallel all the parameter in tensorflow model and torch model?

Comment: Please give more details, give an example

Answer (score 0):

What you want requires reimplementing the model in pytorch and then loading the weights. There doesn't seem to be an automatic conversion method.

See also the datascience stack exchange:

- [link 1](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/56772/converting-a-keras-model-to-pytorch?)
- [link 2](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/40496/how-to-convert-my-tensorflow-model-to-pytorch-model)

Comment: but seems that (for example the implementation of RNN in torch and tf are different and I could not mapping all the weights in tf to torch layers）